# Pass numpy array of list of integers in Cython method from Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numpy, cython

I would like to pass the following array of list of integers (i.e., it's not an two dimensional array) to the Cython method from python code.

**Python Sample Code**:

```
import numpy as np
import result
a = np.array([[1], [2,3]])
process_result(a)
```

The output of `a` is `array([list([1]), list([2, 3])], dtype=object)`

**Cython Sample Code**:

```
def process_result(int[:,:] a):
    pass
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried to pass a *simple array instead of numpy* I got the following error

```
a = [[1], [2,3]]
process_result(a)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Kindly assist me how to pass the value of **`a`** into the **`Cython`** method `process_result` and whats the exact **`datatype`** needs to use to receive this value in **`Cython`** method.

Comment: How do you intend to process this array, especially the lists?  At least in Python, there isn't much of an advantage to creating such array.  A list of those lists is often easier, and faster, to process.  Remember such a list, and array, just contains pointers to the lists, which reside elsewhere in memory.

Comment: Look at `a`.  Is that a 2d array, or 1d?  Count the `[]` or look at its shape.  If that's what you want to pass to `cython`, why are you using `[:,:]` instead of `[:]`?  You may need more experience with `numpy` in interpreted Python before moving on to `cython`.

Comment: @hpaulj - using of 1d `[]` is not an issue, but whats the datatype that I need to use. `def process_result( ??? [:] a):`

Comment: `<void>[:]` might work.  http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting.   `a` `itemsize` is 8, the items being pointers to the lists elsewhere in memory.  Compare `np.frombuffer(a,'int64')` with `id(a[0])`.  So any 8 byte dtype should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong data-type. Instead of a numpy array of lists, you should be using a list of numpy arrays. There is very little benefit of using numpy arrays of Python objects (such as lists) - unlike numeric types they aren't stored particulatly efficiently, they aren't quick to do calculations on, and you can't accelerate them in Cython. Therefore the outermost level may as well be a normal Python list.

However, the inner levels all look to be homogenous arrays of integers, and so would be ideal candidates for Numpy arrays (especially if you want to process them in Cython).

Therefore, build your list as:

```
a = [ np.array([1],dtype=np.int), np.array([2,3],dtype=np.int) ]
```

(Or use `tolist` on a numpy array)

For your function you can define it like:

```
def process_result(list a):
    cdef int[:] item
    for item in a:
        #operations on the inner arrays are fast!
        pass
```

Here I've assumed that you most likely want to iterate over the list. Note that there's pretty little benefit in typing `a` to be `list`, so you could just leave it untyped (to accept any Python object) and then you could pass it other iterables too, like your original numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the **array of list of integer to *list of object*** (i.e., list of list of integers - its not a two dimensional array)

**Python Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import result
a = np.array([[1], [2,3]]).tolist()
process_result(a)
```

The output of **`a`** is `[[1], [2,3]]`

**Cython Sample Code:**

```
def process_result(list a):
    pass
```

Change the `int[:, :]` to `list`. It works fine.

> **Note**: If anyone know the optimal answer kindly post it, It will be
>   helpful.